# Does WebSphere 7 HTTPSession implementation contravene J2EE spec?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, deadlock

Saw a problem recently where all 200 web container threads became hung, meaning none were available to service incoming requests and so the application froze.

Here is a simple web app and JMeter test that I think demonstrates the cause of this problem. The web app consists of two classes, the following servlet:

```
public class SessionTestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected static final String SESSION_KEY = "session_key";

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // set data on session so the listener is invoked
        String sessionData = new String("Session data");
        request.getSession().setAttribute(SESSION_KEY, sessionData);
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();                           
        writer.println("<html><body>OK</body></html>");                      
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

and the following implementation of HttpSessionListener and HTTPSessionAttributeListener:

```
public class SessionTestListener implements 
        HttpSessionListener, HttpSessionAttributeListener {

    private static final ConcurrentMap<String, HttpSession> allSessions 
        = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, HttpSession>(); 

    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent hsbe) {}

    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent hsbe) {
        System.out.println("Attribute added, " + hsbe.getName() 
            + "=" + hsbe.getValue());

        int count = 0;
        for (HttpSession session : allSessions.values()) {
            if (session.getAttribute(SessionTestServlet.SESSION_KEY) != null) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count + " of " + allSessions.size() 
            + " sessions have attribute set.");
    }

    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent hsbe) {}

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent hse) {
        allSessions.put(hse.getSession().getId(), session);                              
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent hse) {
        allSessions.remove(hse.getSession().getId());
    }                
}
```

The JMeter test has 100 requests hit the servlet every second:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.1">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <intProp name="LoopController.loops">-1</intProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">100</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1327193422000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1327193422000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="HTTP Request" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">9080</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/SESSION_TESTWeb/SessionTestServlet</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <ConstantTimer guiclass="ConstantTimerGui" testclass="ConstantTimer" testname="Constant Timer" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">1000</stringProp>
          </ConstantTimer>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
      <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
            <time>true</time>
            <latency>true</latency>
            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
            <success>true</success>
            <label>true</label>
            <code>true</code>
            <message>true</message>
            <threadName>true</threadName>
            <dataType>true</dataType>
            <encoding>false</encoding>
            <assertions>true</assertions>
            <subresults>true</subresults>
            <responseData>false</responseData>
            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
            <xml>true</xml>
            <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            <bytes>true</bytes>
          </value>
        </objProp>
        <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
      </ResultCollector>
      <hashTree/>
      <ResultCollector guiclass="SummaryReport" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Summary Report" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
            <time>true</time>
            <latency>true</latency>
            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
            <success>true</success>
            <label>true</label>
            <code>true</code>
            <message>true</message>
            <threadName>true</threadName>
            <dataType>true</dataType>
            <encoding>false</encoding>
            <assertions>true</assertions>
            <subresults>true</subresults>
            <responseData>false</responseData>
            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
            <xml>true</xml>
            <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            <bytes>true</bytes>
          </value>
        </objProp>
        <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
      </ResultCollector>
      <hashTree/>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

When this test is run against the test web app deployed on WebSphere 7, the application quickly stops responding and a core dump shows this:

```
1LKDEADLOCK    Deadlock detected !!!
NULL           ---------------------
NULL           
2LKDEADLOCKTHR  Thread "WebContainer : 2" (0x000000000225C600)
3LKDEADLOCKWTR    is waiting for:
4LKDEADLOCKMON      sys_mon_t:0x00000000151938C0 infl_mon_t: 0x0000000015193930:
4LKDEADLOCKOBJ      com/ibm/ws/session/store/memory/MemorySession@00000000A38EA0C8/00000000A38EA0D4: 
3LKDEADLOCKOWN    which is owned by:
2LKDEADLOCKTHR  Thread "WebContainer : 1" (0x00000000021FB500)
3LKDEADLOCKWTR    which is waiting for:
4LKDEADLOCKMON      sys_mon_t:0x0000000015193820 infl_mon_t: 0x0000000015193890:
4LKDEADLOCKOBJ      com/ibm/ws/session/store/memory/MemorySession@00000000A14E22C0/00000000A14E22CC: 
3LKDEADLOCKOWN    which is owned by:
2LKDEADLOCKTHR  Thread "WebContainer : 2" (0x000000000225C600)
NULL
```

It appears that when a thread (T1) executing the servlet's doGet() method calls setAttribute() on the instance of HttpSession implementation (S1), it locks on the monitor of S1. While holding that lock it goes into the iteration of allSessions inside the listener's attributeAdded() method and calls getAttribute(). It looks like inside getAttribute(), WebSphere locks on that instance's monitor (possibly because it is setting a lastUpdateTime field?). So, T1 will in turn lock the monitors of S1, S2, S3, S4, S5... all the while holding the lock on S1 from the setAttribute() call in the servlet.

So if at the same time another thread (T2) is locking on another session (S2)'s monitor in the servlet and then goes into the loop in addAttribute(), the threads deadlock on the S1 and S2 monitors.

I have been unable to find anything explicit in the J2EE specs about this but this part of the Servlet 2.4 spec implies that the container should not be synchronizing on instances of HttpSession implementations:

> **SRV.7.7.1 Threading Issues**
>
> Multiple servlets executing request threads may have active access to
>   a single session object at the same time. The Developer has the
>   responsibility for synchronizing access to session resources as
>   appropriate.

JBoss does not show any deadlocks when we run the test against it. So my questions are:

- Is my understanding correct?
- If so, is this a bug or contravention of the J2EE spec in WebSphere?
- If not, and it is valid behaviour that the developer should know about and code around, is this behaviour documented anywhere?

Thanks

Comment: WAS keeps amazing me. Nice testcase. I can't answer from experience or authoritative resources, but I won't be surprised when this is indeed another WAS quirk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Servlet 2.5 MR6 contains a [clarification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr154/servlet-2.5_MR6.html) to the part of the Servlet spec quoted in the question:

> **Clarify SRV 7.7.1 "Threading Issues" (Issue 33)**
>
> Change the paragraph which currently is
>
> "Multiple servlets executing request threads may
>   have active access to a single session object at the same time. The
>   Developer has the responsibility for synchronizing access to session
>   resources as appropriate."
>
> to read
>
> "Multiple servlets executing
>   request threads may have active access to the same session object at
>   the same time. The container must ensure that manipulation of internal
>   data structures representing the session attributes is performed in a
>   threadsafe manner. The Developer has the responsibility for threadsafe
>   access to the attribute objects themselves. This will protect the
>   attribute collection inside the HttpSession object from concurrent
>   access, eliminating the opportunity for an application to cause that
>   collection to become corrupted."

This is still current in Servlet 3.0 MR1 and makes WAS's behaviour look more reasonable. However, I would take from it that **set**Attribute might be synchronized but it not that **get**Attribute would be.

So I think the answer is:

- WAS **is** complying with the Servlet spec according to the clarification in 2.5 MR6
- The spec leaves room for misunderstanding
- WAS is more zealous with its synchronization than would reasonably be expected from the spec and AFAIK this behaviour is not clearly documented anywhere

(As a side note, changing the test case so that listener.attributeAdded() calls setAttribute instead of getAttribute doesn't cause deadlocks on JBoss 4 or 5.)

Answer (score 2):

You have probably found a not supported use case of `HttpSession` in IBM WebSphere specific implementation. Why not report it to IBM ?

A point you have missed for your implementation: the JavaEE container may passivate `HttpSession` objects (by serializing it on disk or database) to free memory if the server has to handle too many sessions under load. Your listener prevents the garbage collector to free that sessions.

By the way, the `HttpSession` object is supposed to be only used by the thread that corresponds to its own session. As you found in specification, in case of multiple concurrent threads from the same session, the code must use synchronization mechanism on the `HttpSession` objet.

Session listeners are event-based with all necessary information in event, such a design is enough to avoid the listener to keep all references to living `HttpSession` objects the way you do.

Quering from one thread all living sessions in the container is strange and unexpected. It is not the job of a web application but of a monitoring or auditing tool. In that case, other means like JMX query or PMI interface in the specific WebSphere context should be used.

To help you, here is an alternate implementation of your listener to achieve the same session attribute count but without keeping any reference on `HttpSession`. Beware: it was neither compiled nor tested.

```
public class SessionTestListener implements 
        HttpSessionListener, HttpSessionAttributeListener {

    private static final Set<String> sessionsIds
        = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>(); 

    private static final ConcurrentMap<String, Object> sessionsKeys
        = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>(); 

    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent hsbe) {
        System.out.println("Attribute removed, " + hsbe.getName() 
            + "=" + hsbe.getValue());
        if (SessionTestServlet.SESSION_KEY.equals(hsbe.getName())) {
            sessionsKeys.remove(hsbe.getSession().getId());
        }
    }

    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent hsbe) {
        System.out.println("Attribute added, " + hsbe.getName() 
            + "=" + hsbe.getValue());

        if (SessionTestServlet.SESSION_KEY.equals(hsbe.getName())) {
            if (hsbe.getValue() == null) {
                sessionsKeys.remove(hsbe.getSession().getId());
            } else {
                sessionsKeys.put(hsbe.getSession().getId(), hsbe.getValue());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sessionsKeys.size() + " of " + sessionsIds.size()
            + " sessions have attribute set.");
    }

    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent hsbe) {}

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent hse) {
        sessionsIds.add(hse.getSession().getId());
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent hse) {
        sessionsIds.remove(hse.getSession().getId());
        sessionsKeys.remove(hse.getSession().getId());
    }                
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yves. Is "the HttpSession object is supposed to be only used by the thread that corresponds to its own session" a guideline or rule or best practice?

Comment: I would say it is the standard use case that rules the HttpSession implementation from the JavaEE container vendors' point of view. Any other use case is only relevant for internal container tools or monitoring/auditing tools. By the way, you still have the limitation to access passivated sessions without container specific implementation details.